# Object* or Object *?

Tags: coding-style

All programming languages I am familiar to (C/C++, Java, C#, Objective C) accept both notations. So I want to know which is semantically correct: `Object* myObj` or `Object *myObj`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, it depends. Both are correct but I generally use the Object*, because the pointer itself can be considered a type and it is more readable.

But there is a problem with that. The pointer in C, by real, is just a modification of a type, and not a real type. If you declare multiple variables in one single line as this:

```
Object *a, b;
```

You will have `a` as a pointer to Object and `b` as one instance of `Object`, so I imagine that the correct way is to put the pointer with the variable.

Comment: this is why many coding style guidelines insist on one variable definition per statement.

Comment: That's right David! And using the one line per declaration I think that the Object* way is more readable! :D

Answer (score 1):

> Which is semantically correct?

Semantically they are identical. Therefore which you use is a matter of taste.

---

Which *taste* should you prefer?  Well, you can write `object* a, b` and think that you have declared two pointers. Of course you have not, you have declared `a` to be a pointer and `b` as an object.

So you should certainly prefer `object *a, b` to `object* a, b`. However, I believe it is better still to have a single line for each variable declaration:

```
object *a;
object b;
```

This approach has no scope for confusion and is recommended by many coding style guidelines.

Comment: They are not semantically equal. One is part of declaration, the other is a part of object.

Comment: They are semantically identical. They mean the same thing. I wonder if your understanding of what the word semantic means is correct?

Comment: As Daniel points out, `object* a, b` declares `a` to be a pointer to `object` and `b` to be an `object`.

Comment: the first way leads to misunderstandings since by writing object* a,b one assumes both a and b have type object*, which is wrong

Comment: That's right. Therefore, you should choose to write `object *a, b`. But better still is to use a new line for each variable declaration. Then there can be no confusion.